# Spring's @Scheduled not running after Hibernate exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, scheduled-tasks, hikaricp

I'm using Hikari CP (5.0.1), Hibernate (5.6.3), hibernate-hikaricp (6.0.0) and I'm getting the connections using HibernateUtil class.
This all works fine, without any issues.

Then I have this `@Scheduled` method that looks like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void runCalculations() {     
        try {
            this.calculateKPIs();                               
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("runCalculations() -> catched exception! - " + t.getMessage(), t);         
        }
    }
    
    private void calculateKPIs() {
        
        Session sessApp = HibernateUtilApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction txApp = sessApp.beginTransaction();
                
        Integer val = (Integer) sessApp.createSQLQuery("some query").uniqueResult();        
        
        txApp.commit();
        sessApp.close();
        
        
    }
```

All is running absolutely fine until once upon a time there is a deadlock on the database level - I'm reading data (every 5 seconds) from tables that are sometimes changed by other program (every 30 minutes).
And when this deadlock happens there is this Exception catched and logged:

```
2022-04-19 08:30:39,760 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (scheduled-task-pool-5) Transaction (Process ID 442) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
2022-04-19 08:30:39,760 ERROR [com.yyy.DW.workers.BW.BWWorker] (scheduled-task-pool-5) BW runCalculations() -> catched exception! - org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute query: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute query
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapLockException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:277)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:98)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1626)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1659)
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.yyy.DW.workers.BW.BWWorker.calculateGenericKPI(BWWorker.java:248)
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.yyy.DW.workers.BW.BWWorker.runCalculations(BWWorker.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor271.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute query
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:120)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2871)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2181)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 442) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:5471)
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1794)
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1052)
    at deployment.xxx.war//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1043)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at deployment.xxx.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    ... 22 more
```

But after this exception is raised and catched, the @Scheduled job is never run again (other @Scheduled jobs are fine). The scheduler's task that ran the job (here `scheduled-task-pool-5`) continues to work and executes other tasks but this one is never run again.

Later in the logs I can see that HikariCP detected and unleaked the leaked connection from this code (as expected).
But I don't really understand why the @Scheduled job is not running again after the catched Exception.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you are using Spring that code is wrong on multiple levels. But the main issue is that when an exception occurs, the session and transaction remain, not closing the database connection leaving the lock (until it times out). To fix put a try/catch/finally in there, or even better properly use the Spring and Hibernate integration with which Spring will properly handle the tx and session management.

Comment: I know it is not the best approach, I'm just trying to keep it working as I inherited the project :). I am aware that the transaction/session is not terminated when Exception occurs but after some timeout the connection is terminated by HikariCP (unleaked) or database server. But i don't really understand why the @Scheduled method is not run again after raising (and catching) the Exception.

Comment: Because you will run out of connections, and it will try to open a new one which it cannot because the pool is exhausted due to the non-existend exception handling. Or your connection is still open and you get a deadlock on the database. Either way, proper exception handling will solve either issue.